# Parse Json String using jackson Parser

Tags: json, jackson

I am able to parse json below:

```
{
    "jobId": "xxx",
    "jobName": "xxx",
    "jobInput": "xxx"
}

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

I need to  parse the below json string using jackson parser in java.

```
{
"Test1": {
    "jobId": "xxx",
    "jobName": "xxx",
    "jobInput": "xxx"
  },
"Test2": {
    "jobId": "xxx",
    "jobName": "xxx",
    "jobInput": "xxx"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Jackson, you can do the following:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
```

If you prefer to use a custom class to hold the values instead of a `Map`, use:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = mapper.readValue(json, Data.class);
```

```java
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("Test1")
    private Job test1;

    @JsonProperty("Test2")
    private Job test2;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Job {

    private String jobId;

    private String jobName;

    private String jobInput;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I did'nt want to use a custom class. the above solution works.Thanks,  its very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about just let Jackson parse a Map? Make the return type as `Map<String, YourFirstDTO>` and I think it will do.